# Openproject Installation getting stuck on the RAILS_ENV="production" ./bin/rake assets:precompile command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, openproject

I am trying to setup OpenProject which is a rails application,on a remote machine via ssh. However on trying the above command the machine gets stuck on Generating browser application bundles (phase: building), and even ctrl+c is not working. I think it might be any of the 3 issues, :

1. Angular issue
2. Rails issue
3. Low memory ( System config.)
   In some previous posts related to Angular projects they suggested making changes to the angular.json file. I wasn't sure if I should do it since this is mainly a RoR project.
   Maybe i can try the --verbose option, but i do not want it to hang again. Any suggestions on what I can possibly do?

Comment: Can you check if you're running out of memory?  Maybe by opening a second terminal and running `top` or `cat /proc/meminfo`.  On some very small cloud servers I've had to add swap temporarily to get past certain gem compilations, but it looks like you're past that stage.  You may also want to run `dmesg` and see if there is anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you do not use the [OpenProject package or Docker image](https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/) for a production installation. Is there a special reason for it? Those packaged installations come with upgrade paths etc. and are much easier to maintain for admins.